# The user geolocation point (blue dot) doesn't appear anymore on my IOS app (works on Android app)

Tags: javascript, ios, actionscript-3

I've got an AIR app (ActionScript 3) that uses Javascript code to create a map.

On Android, the blue dot (geolocation point) of the user is displayed, but on IOS it's not anymore. 
The lattitude and longitude of the user is displayed so I know that the app geolocates the user.

Apple must have change something in an IOS update that prevent my app to create the blue dot on the map...

The code that creates the map is a folder linked to the project (assets/maps). It's a javascript code (mapTools.js)

I must say, it's another developer on Peopleperhour that made me the code a few years ago.

I suppose that the concerns lines are theses (in mapTools.js) :

```
// createPositionFromApp(latitude, longitude, isAddingPositon)
    // lat = a[1], lng = a[2], isAddingPositon = a[3] as Boolean

    if (a[0] == "onCreatePositionFromApp")
    {
        var isAdding = false;
        if (a[3] == "true") isAdding = true; else isAdding = false;

        createPositionFromApp(a[1], a[2], isAdding);
    }

    if (a[0] == "onCreatePositions")
    {
        var isAdding = false;
        if (a[2] == "true") isAdding = true; else isAdding = false;

        createPositions(a[1], isAdding);
    }

}, false);
```

Do you see something that will prevent IOS to create the position on the map ?